# how to execute Testng tests using maven surefire via command line

Tags: command-line, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a testng.xml file to bring in parameters into my test software.

```
<suite name="My suite">
<parameter name="first-name"  value="Cedric"/>
<test name="Simple example">
 <-- ... -->
```

I would like to know how to run a exclude test while using the testng.xml file via command line only.

```
 mvn -DexclueTest=!apiXMLTest test
```

If any packages are needing to be installed or uninstalled this would help.

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=false
```

Maven packages are all up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know exactly what you need.

```
   mvn test -DexcludedGroups=Broken
```

Then add the tag to your test

```
 groups = {"con" , "Broken"},
```

Or if you are using Groovy (Bleh)

```
 groups = ['con' , 'Broken'],
```

Yeah Dtest doesnt work do to the xml grouping

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because your are on unix or cmd but try

```
    mvn -Dtest=!%regex[.*.RESTTest.class#apiXMLTest.*] 
     test
```